# Spring cloud data flow wirh

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

Docker Compose Customization - as per the reference guide if we point to mysql in the dockercompose.yml, will that start the mysql data base process, along with other processes kafka, zookeeper, and dataflowserver, or do we need to first manually start the the mysql database process separately before docker-compose up command.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the docker-compose.yml file to point to mysql configuration, does indeed start a
 springdataflow_mysql_1 container process.

Creation of streams, and deployment persists these definitions to the STREAM_DEFINITIONS TABLE AND STREAM_DEPLOYMENTS respectively under the DATAFLOW database.

Answer (score 0):

Glad you got it working! You can customize to swap the DB or Message Broker of your choice.  The promise of docker-compose is to bring up the described components in an order and there's simple logic (via `depends_on`) that waits for all the middleware components to start. We describe the customization [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.6.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-customizing-spring-cloud-dataflow-docker).

Otherwise, the autoconfiguration will kick-in to configure the environment for the desired database as far as the right driver is in the classpath of SCDF - see supported [databases](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.6.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-rdbms). And yes, we already ship the open-source MariaDB driver, so it works just fine with MySQL.